# The changeLogFile must be specified error on Liquibase

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I am new to Liquibase and i tried to using the liquibase with postgres database to create database tables using liquibase script. What i did is, i already created Postgres tables manually and by running the command

*mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog*

i created liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml file. Now i try to update that script and create one more table in the database. For that i write the XML code in my changeLog.xml file for that new table and try to execute the command

*mvn liquibase:update*

But its giving me below error

The ChangeLogFile must be specified.

Below is my POM.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!--Sonar Plugins-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Could any one of them please help me , whats wrong here.

strong text[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and show us your `pom.xml` and the **complete** command how you invoke Liquibase. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - [edit] your question, please do not post code in comments

Answer (score 4):

You should move to **liquibase** version **4.11.0**

and change `changeLogFile` to `outputChangeLogFile`

Hope that's help

Comment: I'm using 4.6.1 version and THIS works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that in your property file as specified in your pom.xml `<propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>` you have used `ChangeLogFile` (with a capital C) rather than `changeLogFile` (with a lower case C). Note the error message shows the correct casing.

Answer (score 1):

When you change something in **liquibase.properties**, you should compile source code every time. `mvn compile`

Answer (score 0):

For db updates you must specify the property **changeLogFile** in your *pom.xml*, in the plugin *liquibase-maven-plugin* section.
See the snippet:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <configuration>                  
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/updateDb.xml</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Ran on liquibase *4.7.1*

Here the complete MVN log:

```
    bmolino@Betelgeuse:~/git/simbo-repo/simbo/simbo-ws(master)$ /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn liquibase:update
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ----------------< it.invallee.webapp.simbo-ws:simbo-ws >----------------
    [INFO] Building simbo-ws 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:4.7.1:update (default-cli) @ simbo-ws ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [project, pluginDescriptor]
    [INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
    [INFO]   File: src/main/resources/db/liquibase.properties
    [INFO]   'outputChangeLogFile' in properties file is not being used by this task.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Liquibase Community 4.7.1 by Liquibase
    [INFO] ####################################################
    ##   _     _             _ _                      ##
    ##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
    ##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
    ##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
    ##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
    ##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
    ##              | |                               ##
    ##              |_|                               ##
    ##                                                ## 
    ##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
    ##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
    ##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
    ##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
    ##                                                ##
    ####################################################
    Starting Liquibase at 16:05:17 (version 4.7.1 #1239 built at 2022-01-20 20:31+0000)
    [INFO] Set default schema name to public
    [INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File src/main/resources/db/liquibase.properties for changeLog parameters
    [INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:postgresql://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5432/simbo
    [INFO] Successfully acquired change log lock
    [INFO] Reading from databasechangelog
    Running Changeset: src/main/resources/db/updateDb.xml::1::bob
    [INFO] Table department created
    [INFO] ChangeSet src/main/resources/db/updateDb.xml::1::bob ran successfully in 16ms
    [INFO] Successfully released change log lock
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  2.073 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-28T16:05:18+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```